# Mounting Dockerized NFS Share From Outside Host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, nfs

I have an a Dockerized nfs-kernel-server based on the Dockerfile and scripts I found [here](https://github.com/FDT2k/docker-nfs-server).

In my Ubuntu host, I can use the IP address of interface `docker0` to mount the volume.

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 172.17.0.2:/srv/nfs /mnt

mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Feb 20 12:57:14 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=172.17.0.2'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 172.17.0.2 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 172.17.0.2 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 33602
```

When I try to use my public IP to mount instead (even from my host system), it says permission denied:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.120.153:/srv/nfs /mnt

mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Feb 20 12:57:03 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.120.153,clientaddr=192.168.120.153'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.120.153:/srv/nfs
```

When I try with NFS v3, I get this:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 192.168.120.153:/srv/nfs /mnt

mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Feb 20 12:49:48 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.120.153'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

Since the share is already mountable, I am assuming that it is an access/permission problem and not a service problem. What could be the reason behind this problem?

---EDIT---

The following run command changes the error message:

```
docker run -d --privileged \
--name nfs \
-p 2049:2049/tcp \
-p 2049:2049/udp \
-p 111:111/tcp \
-p 111:111/udp \
-p 1066:1066/tcp \
-p 1067:1067/tcp \
-p 1067:1067/udp \
-v /tmp:/srv/nfs \
cpuguy83/nfs-server /srv/nfs
```

Trying to mount with v3 or v4 now results in the same error message:

```
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

I do not have a firewall running and I have already checked that `rpcbind` is running on my host system. When I try the `-o nolock` option, I get the following:

```
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nolock,nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.120.153'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Unable to receive
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused
```

Comment: This is off-topic for SO

Answer (score 2):

As you did not provide the `docker run` command line you used, I assume you used the example from the linked Github repo:

```
docker run -d --name nfs --privileged cpuguy83/nfs-server /path/to/share /path/to/share2 /path/to/shareN
```

This results in the NFS ports not being exposed and thus only being accessible through the private docker IP. Please try:

```
docker run -d --name nfs --privileged -p 111:111/udp -p 2049:2049 cpuguy83/nfs-server /path/to/share /path/to/share2 /path/to/shareN
```

The important part is `-p 111:111/udp -p 2049:2049`

After this, you should be able to mount it by using the public IP.

Please note that you may have to delete the old container first:

```
docker rm -f nfs
```

Comment: I get the following error:

`...
Successfully built 7ccbef71a3f5
823a820d7e27b1020afca27bdc8b9f11d6bf97711926015d86e803577ea13744
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nfs (ab8c13199983da6a7ef24ac26c087f7a38da6dcfeb7391ffbadf988173c3f14a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:2049: bind: address already in use.
Failed to run Docker container!`

Which I think should be expected, because of the following line in the Dockerfile:

`EXPOSE 111/udp 2049/tcp`

Comment: This either means that you already have a container running that listens on public interfaces and the same port or more likely: You already have NFS running  on your host system.